# Reduced APK Size using xamarin platform

Tags: xamarin

i am xamarin developer and i need to reduced apk size.

When using the 'Don't link' linker option, the app size was 40 MB! When switching to 'Link SDK Assemblies', it was 16 MB!
The idea is to use 'Link SDK Assemblies' linker option and do the necessary to make linker do the right thing.

using above step i got solution but i want to more reduced apk size, 
is it possible than?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "Link all assemblies" from the linker settings. But this should be excessive tested on a real device.

Further I would take a look at your resources like images, layouts and supported architectures. Images for example can be optimized with online services like tinypng.com.

[This post](http://motzcod.es/post/112072508362/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down) from James Montemagno my help. Also [this one](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/) from Cyril Mottier is a good read on that topic.